# chrome extension not doing anything with .js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions but trying to setup a XSS detector.  I have the ability to test GET and POST separately so I just have GET programmed now.  The extension loads but when I test from a known site the extension does nothing.  Also setup a console log that gets nothing so I know the extension is just not hooked correctly.  Any help on why this is not working would be much appreciated.

I have tried content_scripts in the manifest.json but then get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined" in the xss_detector.js

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "XSS Detector", 
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "xss detector and frame buster", 
    "permissions": ["tabs", "notifications", "<all_urls>", "webRequest"
    "webRequestBlocking"],
    "background": {
     "scripts": ["xss_detector.js"], 
     "persistent": true
},
    "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "Detects and Busts!",
     "default_icon": "icon.png" 
}
}
```

xss_detector.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {

    const start_script_re = /.*(<div>\s*)?<script>.*<\/script>
    (<\/div>\s*?.*/mi;

    const end_script_re = null;

    if (details.method === "GET") {
    console.log("http get request");
        if (decodeURI(details.url).match(start_script_re)) {
        return {redirectURL:"javascript:"};
    }

    } else if (details.method === "POST") {

    }
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking", "requestBody"]);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "XSS Detector",   
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "xss detector and frame buster", 
  "permissions": ["tabs", "notifications", "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"],
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["xss_detector.js"], 
     "persistent": true
},
  "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "Detects and Busts!",
     "default_icon": "icon.png" 
}
}
```

Comment: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10257301)

Comment: Your start_script_re as posted in the question right now is an invalid regular expression.

Comment: Wow, just seeing that it wasn't closed properly changed to /.*(<div>\s*)?<script>.*<\/script>(<\/div>\s*)?.*/mi;  Still not doing anything though.

Comment: Debug it. Open devtools for the background script, set a breakpoint inside the listener and see what happens on navigation.

Comment: starting that now, thank you for the advice.